# Redirecting via RedirectToAction gives 404 status

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In controller's action is redirected to another action of the same controller. Result: "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found". GetData is called via ajax-request in JQuery. On redirect is requested url http://localhost:61327/Home/Index/qwertyQWERTY%20HTTP/1.1. Request address http://localhost:61327/Home/Index/qwertyQWERTY works fine. Code of controller, ajax-request and RouteConfig.cs is shown below.

Routes

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{d}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", d = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default1",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{data}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetData", data = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

HomeController

```
public ActionResult Index(string d)
{
    Repository repository = new Repository();
    ViewBag.ViewbagValues = repository.GetAllCustomersAndOrders();
    Response.Write("Ku-ku");
    Response.Write(d);            
    return View(repository.GetAllCustomersAndOrders());
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]        
public ActionResult GetData(string data)
{            
    Response.Write(Request.InputStream);
    Response.Write("qwerty");            
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new {d="qwertyQWERTY"});            
}
```

Script

```
function SendDataToController(data) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: "Home/GetData",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "text",
        contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Data was send to the controller");
            window.location = result.URL;
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Error: data was not send to the controller");
        }
    });
    alert(data);
```

Comment: Your making an ajax call. Ajax calls do not redirect (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page). In your success call back, result is a view (html) which does not contain a property named `URL` so its undefined. If you want to redirect, don't use ajax.

Comment: But redirection performed not in ajax-request. It perforned on action. Or the fact that the original used ajax?

Comment: Ajax call **do not** redirect. It returns the response to the same page. There is no point using ajax if you want to redirect - just do a normal submit.

Comment: Can I set "async: false" in "$.ajax()" to solve the problem?

Comment: No. What is it that your wanting to do? If your want to redirect, do not use ajax - its pointless.

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me a lot! If possible, complete your solution as the answer. I think it will be easier for other people. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Stephen Muecke's note - this will work with your javascript:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]        
public ActionResult GetData(string data)
{
  var data = new { URL = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {d="qwertyQWERTY"}) };
  return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
}
```

Comment: So RediretcToAction is unsuitable?